Google Sheets - QUERY Filter by drop down combined with order by dependent drop down
I want to make a student list  more flexible and user-friendly rather than just a large slab of data.
I am looking to combine several different bits of functionality through filtering and sorting while using checkboxes to select or remove columns. The first is using a dependent drop-down list to filter data the data using this formula
=QUERY(O14:V34,"SELECT "&TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ArrayFormula(IF(O13:V13,"Col"&(COLUMN(O14:V14)-COLUMN(O14)+1) ,"")))
& " WHERE Col1 is not null "
&IF(D3="All Teachers",""," AND LOWER(Col1) = LOWER('" &D3&"') ")
&IF(E3="All Schools",    ""," AND LOWER(Col4) = LOWER('" &E3&"') ")
&IF(G3="All",    ""," AND LOWER(Col5) = LOWER('" &G3&"') ") 
 ,1)

The second is giving the option to order/sort the list using a dependent drop-down.
=QUERY(O14:V34,"SELECT "&TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ArrayFormula(IF(O13:V13,"Col"&(COLUMN(O14:V14)-COLUMN(O14)+1) ,"")))
& " WHERE Col1 is not null order by Col"&MATCH(D34, O14:V14, 0)
,1)

When combined (probably wrong anyway) the sorting option will work but only when "All Teachers", "ALL Schools", or "All" but when only one value is selected such "John", it will break as seen in the error below. Otherwise, I can sort the various columns.
=QUERY(O14:V34, "Select "&TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ArrayFormula(If(O13:V13,"Col"&(COLUMN(O14:V14)-COLUMN(O14)+1),""))) 
& " WHERE Col1 is not null ORDER By Col"&MATCH(D34, O14:V14, 0)&" "&G1
 &IF(D3="All Teachers",""," AND LOWER(Col1) = LOWER('" &D3&"') ") 
&IF(E3="All Schools", ""," AND LOWER(Col2) = LOWER('" &E3&"') ")
&IF(G3="All", ""," AND LOWER(Col2) = LOWER('" &G3&"') ") 
,1)

Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "and" "AND "" at line 1, column 93. Was expecting one of: <EOF> "skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ... "format" ... "options" ... "asc" ... "desc" ... "," ... "*" ... "+" ... "-" ... "/" ... "%" ... "*" ... "/" ... "%" ... "+" ... "-" ...
Google Sheet for testing
Here is another solution I attempted to make work that is on the bottom right of the example sheet. This had some success but I wasn't clear on how to bring in more IF statements as I need 4-5 sort options and not simply 2.
=IF( D34="", ,SORT(QUERY(O13:V32,"SELECT "&TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ArrayFormula(IF(O11:V11,"Col"&(COLUMN(O12:V12)-COLUMN(O12)+1) ,"")))
& " WHERE Col1 is not null "
&IF(D3="All Teachers",""," AND LOWER(Col1) = LOWER('" &D3&"') ")
&IF(E3="All Schools",    ""," AND LOWER(Col4) = LOWER('" &E3&"') ")
&IF(G3="All",    ""," AND LOWER(Col5) = LOWER('" &G3&"') ") 
 ,1), IF( D34="Teacher", 1, IF( D34="Home School", 4, 1)), IF( D34="Teacher", True, 1)))

Any help on either the query "ORDER BY" or "Sort()" solution would be amazing. Thanks!
I am still very novice in Google Sheets, especially when working with the query functions but I am  eager to learn.
Thanks!


You may try with moving the ORDER statement after the conditional arguments:
=QUERY(O12:V32, "Select "&TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ArrayFormula(If(O11:V11,"Col"&(COLUMN(O12:V12)-COLUMN(O12)+1),""))) & " WHERE Col1 is not null"
 &IF(D3="All Teachers",""," AND LOWER(Col1) = LOWER('" &D3&"') ") 
&IF(E3="All Schools", ""," AND LOWER(Col4) = LOWER('" &E3&"') ")
&IF(G3="All", ""," AND LOWER(Col5) = LOWER('" &G3&"') ")&"

ORDER By Col"&MATCH(D34, O12:V12, 0)
,1)



Thank you so much that did end up working. I tried several different locations for it but using concatenate there I did not see it as a solution at all. It is much appreciated, I have been experimenting around for far too long trying to get that to work.
